# How to install termite

Tags: command-line, compiling, make

I'm using openbox on UbuntuGnome .. if that helps.

So I reviewed the documentation located here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Termite

and I can't figure out how to install it. 
I'm very novice and would just like a simple explanation is possible, or at least a nudge in the right direction.

I also followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/thestinger/termite

Did the following:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/thestinger/termite.git
cd termite && make
```

then get this:

```
ask@ubuntu:~/termite$ make
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
Package vte-2.91 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `vte-2.91.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'vte-2.91' found
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
Package vte-2.91 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `vte-2.91.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'vte-2.91' found
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Winit-self -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wmissing-declarations -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wunused-macros -Wwrite-strings -DNDEBUG -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -DTERMITE_VERSION=\"v11\"   -Wno-missing-field-initializers -s -Wl,--as-needed  termite.cc  -o termite
termite.cc:31:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'termite' failed
make: *** [termite] Error 1
```

Answer (score 17):

Over [here](https://github.com/Corwind/termite-install) is an install script, that nicely explains all dependencies and stuff, I'll just copy that for you ;)

**Install dependencies**

```
sudo apt install -y g++ libgtk-3-dev gtk-doc-tools gnutls-bin \
    valac intltool libpcre2-dev libglib3.0-cil-dev libgnutls28-dev \
    libgirepository1.0-dev libxml2-utils gperf build-essential
```

**Get and install vte-ng**

```
git clone https://github.com/thestinger/vte-ng.git
echo export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/include/gtk-3.0:$LIBRARY_PATH"
cd vte-ng && ./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install
cd ..
```

**Get and install termite, and setup**

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/thestinger/termite.git
cd termite && make && sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo mkdir -p /lib/terminfo/x
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/terminfo/x/xterm-termite /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-termite
```

Voila, this should be it ....

Comment: You should not be doing `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/terminfo/x/xterm-termite /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-termite` that's a bad idea. What's the point?

Comment: @EvanCarroll if you point out to me why not, I'll change it, but as you might have read in the first paragraph this "solution" is stolen.

Comment: Why you do a echo of `export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/include/gtk-3.0:$LIBRARY_PATH"`?

Comment: This instructions will break your gnome terminal since this requires a newer version of the `vte-ng` package. Do not follow this instructions or your gnome terminal will be affected.

Comment: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'vte-ng': No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way to install is the following:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Corwind/termite-install/master/termite-install.sh
chmod +x ./termite-install.sh
./termite-install.sh
```

Now update your default terminal emulator:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didnt install the required DEPENDENCIES. It could be the problem

> Package vte-2.91 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Try installing vte-ng https://github.com/thestinger/vte-ng

Comment: I did see that, but i'm not sure how install vte-ng. They don't tell you how to install it. 
Do you know how to install vte-ng?

Comment: it should usually be mentioned in the read me file(after download the zip file)

Comment: This is the read me:

* What is VTE?

VTE is a library (libvte) implementing a terminal emulator widget for GTK+,
and a minimal sample application (vte) using that.  Vte is mainly used in
gnome-terminal, but can also be used to embed a console/terminal in games,
editors, IDEs, etc.

VTE doesn't have a homepage.  Report any issues at:

  http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=vte

Comment: try this http://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Answred here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/739563/how-to-compile-and-install-this/739614#739614

Answer (score 0):

you can also install it with those commandas:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install termite --candidate
```

https://snapcraft.io/install/termite/ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

You can Install `termite` on Ubuntu using this script :

[Termite Installer](https://github.com/Corwind/termite-install)

Comment: I don't see how providing the same information in your answer as that which was already provided by the top answer is adding anything.

Answer (score -3):

An easy [viable alternative](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) would be to install [terminator](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=terminator&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) which is easily available for [all currently supported versions of Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases?_ga=1.42209965.905137887.1489066162)

This is a very simple 2 step process.

1) [Enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

2) install terminator either through the Ubuntu software center or via the command line in a terminal with the command `sudo apt-get install terminator`

This might be a better choice as some say that terminator is superior because it can seperate the terminal window into several areas and you can re-size them as needed. Multiple windows and tabs are also supported.

Sources:

Experience

https://www.slant.co/versus/2444/2462/~terminator_vs_termite

Comment: Downvoted because this does not even attempt to answer the problem.
There are many reasons why one would not want to install `terminator`, for example the UI overhead with titlebar and window borders etc. I find `tilix`/`terminix` annoying for the same reasons.

Comment: @BenjaminR Thank you for sharing your views.  Rest assured that I posted this answer in an honest attempt to help with the belief that an alternative solution would be welcome.  Perhaps this question would have had an answer to your liking sooner of you had made an effort to provide one. I'm sure the community would benefit if you would take a more active role. :-)

Comment: You've misunderstood me, but I understand why as my comment is definitely sub-ideal when I read it again. I was merely trying to state that assuming the Asker is not aware of `terminator` or may not have perfectly valid and specific reasons for wanting to use `terminix`, and instead offering this as an answer when it **does not answer the question** definitely deserves a downvote. Any answer which does not answer the question does. Asking "Have you tried terminator instead?" in a comment on the question is totally valid.

Comment: With all due respect, you misunderstand. I provided a viable alternative which is perfectly acceptable under [the guidelines.](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) Here's a quote: "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – **or a viable alternative.**

Comment: I concede the point entirely, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @BenjaminR No problem, I'm always [eager to help](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16264/are-we-truly-eager-to-help)

Comment: Termite is a lightweight terminal emulator. Terminator is a bloated Java 6 Terminal Emulator. I can't see how this is a viable alternative.

Comment: At first, I thought this answer didn't provide a good solution to the question asked, but then I read the comments and not only changed my mind, but I learned more about the community. Thanks @ElderGeek

Comment: @GabrielZiegler Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: There are two terminals named Terminator. The one linked from this _answer_ (which has an Ubuntu package, and is shown with the red title bar on the screenshot comparing to Termite) is written in Python, using the VTE widget. The other one, linked from a followup _comment_, is written in Java.

Comment: @egmont Nice catch. It doesn't appear that there were 2 terminators when I wrote this answer. The follow up comment over a year and a half later (noe deleted) was simply a response to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739163/how-to-install-termite/906308?noredirect=1#comment1803170_906308) reviewing the Java version.  Feel free to edit answers that can be improved.