# How to compile and install this?

Tags: compiling

https://github.com/thestinger/vte-ng

I see a CONFIGURE, autogen.sh and a makefile but I can't seem to figure out how to install this.

Can someone help explain what I need to do to install this?

Comment: Recent release (13 days ago) might be easier: https://github.com/thestinger/vte-ng/archive/0.42.4.a.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

first you will have to make the make file from makefile.am.For this

1. Make sure you have autoconf,  libglib2.0-dev(for AM_GLIB_GNU_GETTEXT   macro), gtk-doc-tools installed 
   `sudo apt-get install autoconf  libglib2.0-dev gtk-doc-tools`
2. goto the /vte-ng-0.42.4.a
3. run command `autoreconf`
4. run command `automake --add-missing` if you get any error
5. Then run `./configure`
6. then you sould have a normal makefile so run `make`
7. run `sudo make install`
   It should be installed