# Gnome terminal stopped working

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/906475/335714) to install termite. Now my Gnome terminal is not starting at all and I only get this error when launching it from termite:

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

I tried to `purge` and `install` again but I still have the same problem.

Even removing the symlink that answer indicated to create has not helped. How can I restore it?

Thanks

Comment: I did not intent to replace it. I am launching it from there because from dash is not starting and I wanted to see the error output. No matter where I launch it from, it never starts.

Comment: Please let them (at the linked answer) know that their instuctions are broken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like installing an old version of  `vte-ng` is incompatible with the the version `gnome-terminal` requires. This is a known bug as posted here.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235680

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/87iush/psa_if_you_have_vte3ng_installed_you_have_to/

I had to run `make uninstall` from the `vtg-ng` folder I downloaded from GitHub to recover my gnome-terminal.

Comment: Installing vte-ng, per se, does not break gnome-terminal. What breaks gnome-terminal is if you install an _older_ version of vte-ng than the system vte, in a way that gnome-terminal will try to load this older vte-ng.